# Text box with datepicker icon in MVC 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I have a textbox and on click it will display the datepicker. However now there is a requirement to add the calendar icon. Datepicker icon must be inside a textbox and whether I click a datepicker icon or the textbox, it should display the datepicker. I am using the following code:

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.myDatePicker, new { @class = "form-control myDatePicker" })
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
```

Since Span is outside  @Html.TextBoxFor calendar icon is displayed in the next line. (Needs 10 reputation point to post images- So not able to add that image)
Is there a way to include calendar icon inside @Html.TextBoxFor?

Or should I add the css to do it?

Any input on this will be helpful.

Comment: I don't think ICONS can go inside the actual TextBox as Textboxes are just for text.  But you could wrap it all in a div I'll post possible answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div>
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.myDatePicker, new { @class = "form-control myDatePicker" })
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</div>
```

or this:

```
<div>   
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.myDatePicker, new { @class = "form-control myDatePicker" })
</div>
```

or this:

```
<div>   
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.myDatePicker, new { @class = "form-control myDatePicker" })
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: any working resolution for this ? since I am having the same question, and did not want to duplicate the question...